# How to recreate private key signature for generating APK?

Tags: android, cordova, apk, private-key

I am working on an app, it is under development yet, it has not been uploaded to store. I had a key on an old HardDrive, and it worked. Now, I changed my HD and when I configured the key again, I realized that I made it under configurations that I didn't wanted (like where it is and alias).

I tried to create a new one, but it just dont do it, returns error.

How can I delete this wrong key? or how can I reconfigure the one that is wrong?

Comment: what is the error you get in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was my mistake of not adding the file name "keyname.keystore", as folder\keyname.keystore.